# nativescript-fonticon for nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript-vue

I am trying to add the plugin: [nativescript-fonticon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-fonticon)

I am currently stuck on the part where I have to convert the css file.

In the readme it states that I have to configure my css and converter before I can start converting:

```
import * as application from 'application';
import {TNSFontIcon, fonticon} from 'nativescript-fonticon';

TNSFontIcon.debug = true; <-- Optional. Will output the css mapping to console.
TNSFontIcon.paths = {
  'fa': 'font-awesome.css',
  'ion': 'ionicons.css'
};
TNSFontIcon.loadCss();

application.resources['fonticon'] = fonticon;
application.start({ moduleName: 'main-page' });
```

How am I supposed to do this in nativescript-vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a blog that actually uses the fonticons plugin and how to use it:
https://nativescript-vue.org/blog/using-fonticons/

**EDIT**:
After a few Nativescript and Nativescript-Vue updates it does not seem to work properly. It's rather hard to use.
I suggest importing the font and using the respective unicodes like this:

Data:

```
icon: '\ue905'
```

Markup:

```
<Label class="ico" :text="icon"/>
```

Comment: This. I got stuck using "#&xe902" while "\ue902" was the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You look like you're on the right track. You should put the initialising code in your `main.js` file (or whatever the entry point file is named).

Here's how to get it to work in NativeScript-Vue.

Download and extract `fontawesome-free-5.9.0-web.zip` from [here](https://fontawesome.com/download).

Add `webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf`, `webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf` and `webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf` to  `app/fonts` directory.

Add `css/fontawesome.css` to `app/assets` directory. Remove any non `fa-*:before` classes from this file.

In your app's `main.js`. You should see a console log for each class when starting your app.

```js
import { TNSFontIcon, fonticon } from 'nativescript-fonticon'

TNSFontIcon.debug = true
TNSFontIcon.paths = {
  'fa': './assets/fontawesome.css',
}
TNSFontIcon.loadCss()
Vue.filter('fonticon', fonticon)
```

In your app's main css file, e.g. `app.scss`.

```css
.fa-brands {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands", "fa-brands-400";
}

.far {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "fa-regular-400";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fas {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "fa-solid-900";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Now use them in your view.

```xml
<Label :text="'fa-facebook-f' | fonticon" class="fa-brands" />
<Label :text="'fa-eye' | fonticon" class="far" />
<Label :text="'fa-eye' | fonticon" class="fas" />
```